How to connect Smartelex 10D DC Motor Driver HAT for Raspberry Pi 3 with 24V 100W motor and 24V 10Ah battery?
I recently acquired the Smartelex 10D DC Motor Driver HAT for my Raspberry Pi 3, intending to control a 24V 100W motor powered by a 24V 10Ah battery. However, I'm uncertain about the wiring configuration and which libraries to utilize for programming. Could someone provide detailed instructions on how to wire the components together, and recommend suitable libraries for controlling the motor? Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
User manual: https://robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/SmartElex-10D-DC-User-Manual.pdf

try asking robu.in tech support first
